# Python: efficient way of combining 2 differently delimited csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have written the following code to combine a Tab-separted csv file with another Comma-separated csv file (which has header too). The final output is a Tab-separated csv, without header.

```
    with open('train.csv',"r") as infile1, open("test.csv", "r") as infile2, open('final.csv',"a") as outfile:
        reader1 = csv.reader(infile1, delimiter='\t')
        reader2 = csv.reader(infile2)
        next(reader2, None)  # skip the headers
        
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader1:
        writer.writerow(row)
        for row in reader2:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Below are sample file for `train.csv` and `test.csv` respectively

```
main-captions   MSRvid  2012    0001    5.000   A plane.    is taking off.
main-captions   MSRvid  2012    0004    3.800   A man.  is playing a flute.

Domain,Task Name,Year,Index,Score,Sentence 1,Sentence 2
Exp,Exp,2020,1,5,product,damage
Exp,Exp,2020,2,5,product,broken
```

The above code works fine.

But is there a shorter way to achieve this? Say, that makes use of any new packages or maybe features within `csv` module?

Comment: You could implement this with `pandas` (if available in your env/dist), then load both, merge and save. For large csv, this should be faster. Could you provide some sample output, so I can test the implementation?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but why do you open `outfile` as `a` if you write the entire content in one run? Alternatively, you could just copy `train.csv` and then use `a` on that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already efficient. But it can be shortened further using `writer.writerows`

```
    from itertools import chain
    writer.writerows(chain(reader1, reader2))
```

Comment: Or use `writer.writerows`?